# Smart Screen Filter with standard Code signing certificate

Tags: code-signing, windows-10-desktop, smartscreen

I signed my Windows Application (this MSI file) with a standard Code signing Certificate (no EV Certificate) to avoid the Smart Screen Filter on Windows 10 to appear and unsettle the
User with the message that my application is a possible danger for the PC.

But even with signign my MSI file with the standard Code Certificate the Smart Screen Filter
appeared. It seems to be that my application needs to get some reputation to pass
the Smart Screen Filter even with a non EV Code signing certificate. My certificate is
issued by Comode (Sectigo)

https://www.digicert.com/blog/ms-smartscreen-application-reputation/

So what kind of reputation do I need to get on the whitelist of the Smart Screen Filter?

Regards

Michael

Comment: I have the same question. I know for an immediate trust you need an EV certificate, but these all require some USB dongle and a manual login process, which is unusable on a (virtual) build server. @Michael did you find out anything in the meantime?

Comment: sorry @Anse no news about this

Comment: Thanks Michael. I decided to go with an OV certificate, which are available without hardware factor from some providers (e.g. Sectigo). Yes, OV certifictes need some time to establish reputation, but not too long, as I read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/188727/153670).